# cannot append value onto array because self is immutable

Tags: swift

I need to append some values onto an array during at the end of a decoder function, I'm hitting the error `cannot use mutating member on immutable value: self is immutable`.

my code is this:

```
var dogs: [Dog] = []

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    let dogids = try values.decode([String].self, forKey: .dogs)
    
    
    
    let ref = try values.decode(DocumentID<DocumentReference>.self, forKey: .ref)
    
    id = ref.wrappedValue?.documentID
   
    name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    address = try values.decode(Address.self, forKey: .address)
    contacts = try values.decode([Contact].self, forKey: .contacts)
    notes = try values.decode([String].self, forKey: .notes)
    
    getDogs(dogids)
}

func getDogs(_ ids: [String]){
    let dogRepository = DogRepository()
    for id in ids {
        dogRepository.get(byId: id) { dog in
            self.dogs.append(dog)
        }
    }
}
```

i'm retrieving customer details from a firestore database, there is a many-many relation between customers and dogs so i am storing the dogs as their document id's on firestore in the customer's document.

the decoder needs to retrieve the dog documents for each associated ID and append it to a `dogs` array.

it is the line `self.dogs.append(dog)` that is throwing out this error.

can anyone see my mistake?

thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cannot+use+mutating+member+on+immutable+value%3A+self+is+immutable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Tarun Tyagi for suggesting i look at this question:

[Swift 5 : What's 'Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter' and how to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58327013/swift-5-whats-escaping-closure-captures-mutating-self-parameter-and-how-t)

the first answer i read indicated that structs cannot be mutated. My data models were all structs and as such `self` was a struct which was being passed into the closure.

All i had to do was change the `struct` declaration to a `class` declaration

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the function signature to indicate to compiler that this can change the contained values.

```
mutating func getDogs(_ ids: [String]) {
```

Comment: I tried this and now i have `escaping closure captures mutating self parameter` (highlighting the `.get()` method line

could this be an issue in the `dogRepository.get()` method body?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58327013/swift-5-whats-escaping-closure-captures-mutating-self-parameter-and-how-t & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60698792/swiftui-escaping-closure-captures-mutating-self-parameter

Comment: okay, important lesson.... Make model objects classes instead of structs.... now i'm going to change all my models to classes, just to be safe haha. Thanks